# scrollRangeToVisible scrolls differently than in-app scroll to-top

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I am trying to scroll to the beginning of my UITextView after the user is done editing. This works fine:

```
[textView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange(0, 0)];
```

However, I get a different result if the user scrolls to the very top; if the user scrolls to the top, the UITextView has a nice padding. If I do it programatically, it doesn't. I attached a screenshot to clarify this.

How would I achieve the same thing programatically, i.e. that there won't be a difference if the user scrolls to the top of the app?

Would I need to do something with scrollRectToVisible? [textView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0) animated:YES]; did not work, though... but perhaps I'm sending the wrong parameters.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer: This seems to have stopped working with iOS 14.**

This may be stupid, but have you tried using a negative y value, like

```
[textView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, -1, 0, 0) animated:YES];
```

? I have no if this works though. Also, I'm not sure if it works properly for a rect of zero width and size, so I'd rather use

```
[textView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, -1, 1, 1) animated:YES];
```

Comment: This does not work. (At least now in iOS14)

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw time to delete it then ... and I can't because it's the accepted answer 

Comment: Hate that! I removed my downvote in lieu of your edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the following to get the top padding included in the scroll action:

```
[yourTextView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
```

Using scrollToRect doesn't work for some odd reason, even still in iOS14, only to point.